# NSMutableArray Crash When checking for count

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, unrecognized-selector, nsnull

I'm using `NSMutableArray` with object name `myArray` :  When there is no data from server My mutable array print

In next line of code if  check for count it crashes. How to resolve this please help me.

```
 NSLog(@"Print Array : %@", myArray);
 if(myArray.count > 0 ){

      Excute code
 }
```

Error:

> Print Array :    2015-01-24 10:44:59.852 RemoteAccess[1061:60b]
>   -[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x38b21a60

Comment: How do you declare, initialize and set myArray? Because it seems like it equals null...

Comment: error says your array is null. check the allocation of array

Comment: @AshishKakkad No, it's not `null`. It's an instance of `NSNull`. Important difference.

Answer (score 2):

You think `myArray` is an array, but it's not - it's an instance of the class [`NSNull`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/index.html). Most likely, you're pulling it out of a JSON feed, and the JSON isn't returning an array, but rather `null`.

The simplest fix is to replace your conditional to check what class you actually got:

```
if ([myArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && myArray.count > 0) {
   // Do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because your `myArray` is nil. You have to make sure that `myArray` is not nil.

Comment: It isn't `nil`. It's an instance of `NSNull`.